# How to repeat part of the last (first) line of the previous (next) page in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, pagestyle

For example, [image]

Is there a way to do this automatically in LaTeX?

Comment: it's tricky and delicate but possible in some cases, but your image seems to show a partial line, a paragraph break and the first line of the next paragraph all being carried over which is trickier than just the last line (and possible in less cases)  If you use luatex more things are possible than if you use pdftex or xetex